# Crystal Reports Pass database fields as parameter for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, sql-function

I have a Stored Procedure/SQL function that makes calculations on a specific record returning 0.00 or another DEC value. It takes the record's primary key as a parameter.

I want to implement this function/Stored procedure in Crystal Reports by passing the primary key database field for each individual record. However, when I try to do this, it requires me to manually input the id. The crystal report that I implement is grouped by the id so that there'll be a report for each record.

Is there a way I can pass a database field as a parameter for a Stored Procedure or a SQL function? Is there something similar I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to insert a subreport using the SP as its data source into the Group Header section. Pass the ID as the **subreport link**, so it gets used as the SP parameter.
If you need the returned value in main report calculations, use a subreport formula to load the value into a Shared variable so it is accessible to main report formulas.

Another option is to use a Crystal Reports **UFL** (User Function Library). Ken Hamady maintains a list of UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl). At least one of them provides a function that allows you to call a dynamic SQL statement and return a value.

Comment: On the first approach, I've created the main report which is grouped by the ID with each page having information on each record. How do I pass the ID to the subreport? I'm kinda new to Crystal Reports, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Start by creating a free-standing report that uses the stored procedure as the data source. The stored procedure parameter would automatically become a Crystal Reports parameter. Test it works.  Then, go into the main report and insert that subreport. Then, Right-Click the subreport and select 'Change Subreport Links'. Pass the ID from the main report to the subreport as a link. Use the drop-downs at the bottom of the dialog to map the passed value to the subreport parameter.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot! How about if you need to return the value for the main report calculations as mentioned in the second part? You said to use the subreport value and make a shared variable to the main. How would I do that part?

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to edit a comment to include code, so I'm posting as a new answer to address your new question:

In the subreport, use a formula to declare and set the value of a shared variable. For example:

```
Shared numbervar CalcResult := {SP_Column_Providing_The_Result};
```

In the Main Report, in a section BELOW the subreport, simply declare the same shared variable. And use it. It will return the value from the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to execute some code (a stored procedure or function) which uses the value of a column as the input to the code, and you want to do that for multiple rows at once.

If you write the code as a user defined function (ideally an [inline table valued function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/creating-and-using-inline-table-valued-functions)), which is sort of like a view that takes a parameter, then you can use [cross apply or outer apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) to execute the code for each row.

Here's a simple example. Suppose I have a block of code written as a user defined function. It takes an integer input parameter and just adds one to the input parameter:

```sql
create or alter function MyFunction(@MyParam int) returns table as 
return
(
   select @MyParam + 1 as MyResult
);
go
```

Because this function returns a table, I get the result by selecting from it, just like selecting from a regular table or view, like this:

```sql
select MyResult from MyFunction(68);

-- returns a result set with a single row and column, with a value of 69
```

But the input parameter value can also come from values in a column. We provide the value for each row by cross applying the function to the table, because "cross apply" means "run this function for each row". Suppose I have some table with 2 rows in it:

```sql
create table MyTable(i int primary key);
go
insert MyTable(i) values (1), (2);
```

I want to run my function against all of the values of `i` in the table. I do this using `cross apply`, and I pass the name of the column as the input parameter:

```
select      f.MyResult
from        dbo.MyTable         t
cross apply dbo.MyFunction(t.i) f;
```

The above code returns the following result set:

| MyResult |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |